# How to change layout 1 column?

Tags: magento2, layout

I am using **Magento 2.1.7**. In My theme I want define module `1column.xml` like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="empty"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="custom.header.container" label="Page Header Container" htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
        <container name="custom.page.top" label="After Page Header" after="custom.header.container"/>
        <container name="custom.footer-container" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

But when I load page it accept both layout `1column` in `core` and layout `1column` in `mytheme`.

Any body help me how to define my layout with name is 1column.xml

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to your custom 1column.xml. It will remove core layout.

```
<referenceBlock name="header.container" remove="true" />
<referenceBlock name="page.top" remove="true" />
<referenceBlock name="footer-container" remove="true" />
```

Comment: Many thanks @shpatel, so another one i can create new layout replace layout 1column.

Comment: Put this code to existing code after in new layout